# How do I find the next date after a specific date for a group of users?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to shift the 'start date' of a subset of users based on when they installed a mobile application. For users who downloaded and installed the application prior to vars_joindate they are considered old users. Users who downloaded and installed the application after vars_joindate they are considered new users.

Old users need to be subsetted, but I can't figure out how to do it. I am trying to determine when they opened the application after the vars_joindate.

```
    DECLARE vars_joindate DATE DEFAULT '2021-01-01';
    DECLARE vars_status STRING DEFAULT 'old';
    DECLARE vars_app STRING DEFAULT 'testapp';


     
    WITH dates AS(
        SELECT JoinDate FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(vars_joindate), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS JoinDate),

users AS(
   SELECT username, operating_system, app_name
   FROM user_table AS A
   WHERE app_name=vars_app),
    
status AS(
   SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT user, app, date_utc, 
            CASE WHEN joindate >=vars_joindate THEN joindate ELSE vars_joindate END AS JoinDate,
            CASE WHEN join_date_utc >= vars_joindate THEN 'new' ELSE 'old' END AS status
            FROM users AS A
            JOIN app_activity AS B
            USING (user, operating_system app)
            WHERE app=vars_app AND operating_system=vars_platform AND swrve_session_start)
          WHERE status=vars_status),
```

The issue I am having is with this statement

```
CASE WHEN joindate >=vars_joindate THEN joindate ELSE vars_joindate END AS JoinDate,
```

because when I shift the user's join date it recodes to the specific date I declared, when I want to change it to the first date they triggered activity after the date I declared.

Comment: please share the sample data and also what is expected output.

Comment: Hi, on this line you’re missing a comma “,” `USING (user, operating_system, app)`,  Also you’re missing the “On” after the “Join” that you have. 

1)Can you share an example of the  info that is on the table users and app_activity?
2)Is the table user_table the same as users?
3)Could you share the sample data and the output you want to get?